# Batch: reading textfile containing list of files with enviromental variables (e.g.: %appdata%) won't get "resolved" when used

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (.\a.config) do (
echo "%%A"
copy /y "%%A" .
)
```

If a line in a.conf contains an environmental variable I just get that echoed (e.g.: "%appdata%......") not the absolute path. How to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (.\a.config) do (
  call echo "%%A"
  call copy /y "%%A" .
)
```

To save having to type `call` in front of every line that uses %%A, you can assign it to a variable:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (.\a.config) do (
  call set expandedA=%%A
  echo "!expandedA!"
  copy /y "!expandedA" .
)
```

Comment: uh, I knew this tens of years ago, but forgot. Thank You for your help!